# Featuring a curve to create a centered gradient

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I'm trying to recreate a graphic I made back in 2007 with Photoshop 7 and I can't duplicate what I did back then with Photoshop CC. Well, as far as my memory is taking me...

I created the graphic using the pen tool and feathering with Adobe Photoshop 7 back in the day. I'm trying to recreate the image as a vector and to use a different color with the same feathering/gradient as the one from the original.

I have the original PSD file, although it appears that I must have either flattened the layers or I was working with paths or even worst, Photoshop CC flattened the Photoshop 7 PSD file???

Does anyone have an idea how I would go about duplicating this graphic?

[image]

Comment: I think just applying a good amount of inner glow to the shape should get you there. In Illustrator: `Effect > Stylize > Inner Glow`.

Comment: I removed the Illustrator tag because, well, nothing in the question relates to Illustrator. Are you seeking an Illustrator method?

Comment: @Scott, I add the Illustrator tag in case someone had a better method with Illustrator instead of Photoshop. Thanks though! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a two node closed shape with blurred interior. A comment suggests effect (in PS it's a layer style) Inner Glow. That's good because the blur is automatically clipped from outside.

[image]

Top left = a screenshot of your image

Top middle = a stroke only version

Top right = no stroke, white fill, green inner glow, blending: normal

Bottom = layered a transparent green version over the previous shape to reduce the white.

The glow radius setting is very steep, it's difficult to find the right radius with the slider. Numerical input probably would give the right result in single layer.

Unfortunately I have not option "center" in lthe inner glow filter. If you have, then this is easy. Only green fill and white inner glow with reduced opacity.

Comment: Thanks! Very simple drawing I know, it was the inner glow I was having difficulty recreating.  I was very tempted to load up PS7 just to do it the way I recalled...

Comment: in PS7 I just created the shape and then used "I think" filter -> feather at about 20. Again that was back in 2007 when i created my companies logo at the time.

Comment: @TAG I have still PS7 installed in one machine which contains much software that was legacy stuff already in 2010. I maintain that WinXP machine and use it frequently (no internet for obvious reasons).  I have found that with that legacy machine I could still earn my bread if the lack of internet was not taken into the account.

Comment: Yes sir, I too had my XP setup until recently. Doesnt take much nowadays to launch a VM instance to run what I need.

Answer (score 0):

In **Illustrator**, you can merely click once in the center of the solid color shape to convert the object to a *Gradient Mesh*. Then adjust the color and handles of that central mesh point.

[image]

Comment: thanks. Your answer is why I tagged it for Illustrator as well. Looks like there is more control as to where the gradient is applied. Plus if I see that correctly, there is an option for transparency!